# Neo4j failed to start on ubuntu

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j

I'm working with neo4j on AWS server ec2 ubuntu instance.

Everything worked great, but when I created an image of my ec2 instance, the instance had to reboot and every since i can't get my neo4j db server to run.

the only thing I see in my console.log file is the following:

```
2015-05-01 16:50:18.135+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
2015-05-01 16:50:18.304+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully stopped database
2015-05-01 16:50:18.304+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully shutdown database.
2015-05-01 16:53:34.972+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2015-05-01 17:08:22.223+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2015-05-01 17:08:49.951+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2015-05-01 17:10:06.715+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2015-05-01 17:10:44.192+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2015-05-01 17:12:36.974+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2015-05-01 17:13:28.628+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2015-05-01 17:22:54.172+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2015-05-01 17:25:42.891+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2015-05-01 17:30:59.901+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2015-05-01 17:32:29.831+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2015-05-01 17:43:13.906+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
```

the server always says it failed to start, and I don't know what to do or where the problem is at..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Because the server default start in (1200000ms)2minutes,it will fail over the time limit.
1.Check the /path/data/graph.db(or your db)/message.log
2.set /path/conf/neo4j-server.properties and add the 3rd step in it

3.org.neo4j.server.startup_timeout=0

the set is to disable the startup limit behavior.

Comment: or  maybe you need to execute    "./neo4j restart"

Answer (score 0):

You should assign an **IAM role to your instance**.
When neo4j is loading it executes this script:

```
/etc/neo4j/pre-neo4j.sh
```

which is calling:

```
aws ec2 describe-tags ...
```